# Writing ATA driver LBA28 messed with LBA48

Tags: size, driver, hardware, hard-drive, ata

I'm currently trying to get LBA working for my ATA driver, but I have problem.

My `identify` function returns OK and `word 83;bit 10` of returned identification data is set, so my device supports LBA48. But when I try to get total amount of LBA48 sectors (configuration words 100-103), it gives my zero. In virtual machine I have 1GB disk set, but this field is still zero. I also tried to get amount of LBA28 sectors => it's the correct one.

Interesting is that when I print out `heads * cylinders * sectors_per_track`, the value is almost same as value of total LBA28 sectors located on words 60-61. It's `2097152` for total LBA28 and 2096640 for `h * c * s`. Difference of these two values is `512`.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?
Is there any other way for getting the size of HDD?

Comment: (+1) for a question other than "how do I compare two strings in Java?"